# Connection -MongoDB & SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, replication, symmetricds

I need to create a connection between ##MongoDB## and ##SQL Server## where I want to replicate a subset of my Database from SQL Server into MongoDB. Can anyone suggest for feasibility of the same and how ?

Right now I am using symmetricDS for the replication but unable to...

Please suggest if symmetricDS is able to serve for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you target MongoDB:

http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.8/html/user-guide.html#_mongodb

If you need more flexibility than straight table to table mapping, then you would write your own data loader using the MongoDatabaseWriter as a pattern.

https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-ds/tree/0c5cc1c24b42a64405f4b79c3cb6b594a35467f2/symmetric-client/src/main/java/org/jumpmind/symmetric/io

Comment: Hi Chenson,  I need to replicate from sql server to MongoDB (unidirectional)  so whether i choose "simple 2 tier configuration" or "Multinode to target" configuration.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Can you rephrase it?

Comment: While using symmetricds Pro and setting the configuration we need to select between "simple 2 tier configuration" or "Multinode to target" configuration. what should i opt for ?

Answer (score 1):

Got an easy way around for the Data Exchange from **SQL to MongoDB** using:

1. SQLtoMongo C# Tool
2. KNIME Analytics Platform (way easy to implement - Opensource)

But still looking for something with triggers to easily replicate the things.